# jquery plugin firing multiple times

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, namespaces

I have a plugin that compares 2 fields in a form and makes alerts depending on the results.
it works fine, except for when I have multiple forms.  however many forms I have on the page, the plugin runs that same number of times.  Is this a namespacing issue?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  (function( $ ){
    $.fn.totalPressedQuantityCheck = function(){
      var form = $(this).parents('form');
      var total_pressed_field = form.find('input[id*="total_pressed"]');
      var variation_quantity_field = form.find('input[id*="quantity"]');

      var total_pressed_amount = parseInt(total_pressed_field.val());
      var variation_quantity_amount = parseInt(variation_quantity_field.val());

      if ( !isNaN(total_pressed_amount) && !isNaN(variation_quantity_amount) ){

        if ( total_pressed_amount < variation_quantity_amount ){
          alert("PROBLEM");
        }
      }
    }
  })( jQuery );

  $('input[id*="total_pressed"]').live('blur', function(){
    $(this).totalPressedQuantityCheck();
  });
  $('input[id*="quantity"]').live('blur', function(){
    $(this).totalPressedQuantityCheck();
  });
```

**FIX**
one of those things... my js ended up in my loop and was getting rendered in the HTML multiple times. Thanks for the jsfiddle site.  I was able to easily distill my code down and narrow down the problem with it.  I wish I knew about this site before!

Comment: Changes parents('form') to closest('form') and then post us the html for this form. Post a jsfiddle of your setup - jsfiddle.com

Comment: wow.  jsfiddle is amazing.  here is my js & html. http://jsfiddle.net/kJAAF/1/

Comment: i realize how terrible that code is to work with. i was making dinner simultaneously.  let me redo that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so my js ended up in my loop and was getting rendered in the HTML multiple times. dur. and thanks for the jsfiddle site. i was able to easily distill my code down and narrow down the problem with it. i wish i knew about this site before!

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is that when you associate the plugin

```
 $('input[id*="total_pressed"]').live('blur', function(){
    $(this).totalPressedQuantityCheck();
  });
```

This will tie any inputs from both forms to this function.  All you have to do is use a more specific selector.

Comment: well any input from any form SHOULD call that plugin.  i shouldn't have to make separate bindings for each form should i?  sometimes there will be 4 or 5 forms.

Comment: no i probably wouldn't make separate bindings but i would pass in a value to tell you what form to grab or what pairing of fields the component should grab